# Tailwind - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

Starting off learning react native and stuck on this error.
[IOS App emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx2xM.png)
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jQnM.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import tw from "tailwind-rn"


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={tw("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      <button title="Click me" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Trying to test out tailwind. Installed all dependencies.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, did you search for that error message here or with Google before posting? It has been asked and answered several times before, so surely one of the existing answers should give you a place to start figuring out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Usage](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn#usage) for `tailwind-rn` says you should import `useTailwind` hook:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn';


export default function App() {
  const tw = useTailwind();

  return (
    <View style={tw("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      <button title="Click me" />
    </View>
  );
}
```